# Hibernate criteria projection distinct

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Hi i want to write a query using criteria :
The following query has to be created using criteria:

"Select Distinct(s2Taxper) from S2 where s2Tc='601' AND s2Txcd!=''"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
Criteria criteria = 
    session.createCriteria(S2.class)
           .add(Restrictions.eq("s2Tc","601"))
           .add(Restrictions.ne("s2Txcd",""))
           .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("s2Taxper")));
```

Comment: projection returns array of objects ( Object[] ) , is there any way to get object of custom classes even after using projection? like in the above answer if I want list<S2> then ?

Comment: We can get by the below code. 
criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(S2.class));

Comment: I got this error: `ERROR [http-nio-8443-exec-8] SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(146) | ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list` after using setProjection().