# get id with distinct with hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to fetch rows with distinct batch code and id.

The below code is now fetching duplicate batch codes like:

> batch1  12,
>   batch1  45,
>   batch1  63,
>   batch2  96,
>   batch2  96

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "key")
public class Key implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 11)
    @Column(name = "batch_code", nullable = false)
    private String batchCode;

    //getter , setter
}



Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Key.class);

ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("batchCode"));

c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));
c.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

if (searchTerm != null && !searchTerm.isEmpty()) {
    c.add(Restrictions.like("keyCode", searchTerm.toUpperCase() + "%"));
}

c.setFirstResult(currPosition);
c.setMaxResults(pageSize);

List<Key> result = c. list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the scenario you are trying is not valid. Batch code and id field is not a unique combination neither a composite key. Now in below table if you need only unique batch code you can create SQL query like “Select distinct batchcode from ” but what I understand from the conversation is you are expecting a complete record batchcode and id for distinct batch code. In this scenario how system determine which record needs to return for any duplicate batch code i.e abc. Here system don’t have any hint whether to return (1, abc) or (2, abc) or (4, abc).
If this is the use case then you need to validate the business scenario what actually you are trying to achieve.

### Id | BatchCode

### 1  | abc

### 2  | abc

### 3  | xyz

### 4  | abc

5  | klm

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are setting multiple projections in criteria. The last one overriding the earlier one. To avoid this you can use ProjectionList to add multiple projections like below

```
    Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Key.class);
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
    projList.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("batchCode")));
    projList.add(Projections.property("id"));
    c.setProjection(projList);
      if (searchTerm != null && !searchTerm.isEmpty()) {
          c.add(Restrictions.like("keyCode", searchTerm.toUpperCase() + "%"));
      }
    c.setFirstResult(currPosition);
    c.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    List<Key> result = c. list();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but is it possible to return all the records with distinct.

Comment: I did not understand your meaning by "all the records with distinct". There was a slight change in the above snippet I have posted. projection list will not require the distinct clause.

Comment: actually your code is not working..showing grammer exception.

Comment: yes. it requires a slight change. I have updated the above snippet. Try that.

Comment: i'm not getting result as expected..batch code is repeating more than 2 times.

Comment: could you please provide your expected results.

Comment: i want distinct batch code with their id like,
 `csc 1
 bsc 2
hhhd 8`

Answer (score 2):

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516661/hibernate-distinct-query-returning-two-columns-result) that is similar to yours but it has not been solved.

In the comments, the OP stated that this little change may be the solution of your problem:

```
 ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
 projList.add(Projections.property("batchCode"));
 projList.add(Projections.property("id"));     
 c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));
```

Notice also that in the above linked question no entity class is set to the `Criteria`.

```
 Criteria c = this.createCriteria();
```

So a `List<Object[]>` is returned by the execution of the list method. I don´t know if you're gonna get a ClassCastException trying to obtain `Key` objects